# UITableViewCell not able to adjust height based on the dynamic CollectionView it contains

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So let me start by explaining the view hierarchy.
I'm using a normal UITableView, inside the UITableViewCell there is a collectionView which is dynamic in height.

How I'm setting the datasource and delegate for UICollectionView at the willDisplay cell of UITableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        guard let collectionCell = cell as? movieListingTableViewCell else { return }

        collectionCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
        collectionCell.selectionStyle = .none
    }
}
```

The collectionView has the top, bottom, leading, trailing and height constraints.

[image: Constraints]

Then I'm using the height constraint and setting it to the collectionView height as so in the UITableView cell subclass,

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

    timingCollectionHeight.constant = timingCollection.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

What happens is that my cells are not appearing properly as in there are blank spaces. For eg, if there is one UITableView cell which has a collectionView with a large height, other UITableView cells also somehow use the same height. After scrolling through the table the cells appear correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Example**

First, get an outlet of your collectionViewHeightConstraint in your tableViewCell Class as shown below:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then inside viewDidLoad() method of your ViewController Class add below code for dynamic height of tableViewCell:-

```
myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;  // Default tableViewCell height
myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Then inside your tableView cellForRowAtindexPath delegate add below code to update the height of tableView Cell as per CollectionView height:-

```
cell.frame = tableView.bounds;  // cell of myTableView
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.myCollectionView.reloadData()
cell.collectionViewHeight.constant = cell.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
```

Hope this helps.
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:
After setting UITableView cell height to be dynamic.

```
     tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
     tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

1. Create a subclass for collectionView and override intrinsicContentSize.

   ```
   class DynamicCollectionView: UICollectionView {
       override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
           if !__CGSizeEqualToSize(bounds.size, self.intrinsicContentSize) {
               self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
           }
       }

       override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
           return collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
       }
   }
   ```
2. In Interface builder change the class of your collectionView to DynamicCollectionView (subclass UICollectionView).
3. Set estimated cell size of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

   ```
       flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1,height: 1)
   ```